# Store PII information in a secure way in NFT token

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, nft

Is it possible to store in a safe way some Personally Identifiable Information (PII) information in a secure way in NFT token so it will not be accessible for everyone, but only for some authorized persons? If so, how to control authorized persons there and provide the permissions to view the info on demand?

Comment: Most blockchain networks are public, so they are not really suitable for storing sensitive data. Plus I'd be very hesitant to store even encrypted sensitive data on a public blockchain - it's the same security risk as allowing read access to another database holding encrypted private data... What is your intention/goal for this approach or storing PPI related to NFT? Maybe there's a solution using a private blockchain network, or an offchain service storing the data accessible through some onchain authorization.

Comment: Our project would like to help users to sell their data to the interested clients. How about to store PII data in our internal secure storage and use the NFT just like access key to such a data?

Comment: curious how this was eventually solved.